# "Too many open files" error when using named pipes

Tags: ruby, named-pipes, file-descriptor, rmagick

I'm running 2 scripts and after a while, I'm getting `Too many open files @ error/blob.c/ImageToFile/1832`.

Simplified version of the first scripts. It's supposed to read images written to image_pipe, process them, and write them to ocr_pipe for the OCR to read.

```rb
# creates 2 named pipes
File.mkfifo(image_pipe) rescue nil
File.mkfifo(ocr_pipe) rescue nil

while image = Image.read(image_pipe)
  # do some stuff with `image`...
end
```

The second script is using ffmpeg to extract frames from a video, writing them to `image_pipe`

```rb
# image_pipe is the same as the script above.

(14..movie.duration).step(0.5) do
  `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg [some options...] #{image_pipe}`
end
```

I think the issue is RMagick opening too many file descriptors when reading the images in the loop of the first script, but I'm not sure how to stop that from happening. The `Magick::Image` class doesn't have a `close` method or anything, afaik.

Comment: Does rmagick offer you a way to close the image you just opened? If yes, you could try doing something like `image.close()` at the end of your loop so you free that file descriptor.

Comment: One of the first thing I tried, but there's no `close` method. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/Magick/Image Can't find anything related to that in there.

Comment: You could try to first narrow down the problem by using something like `lsof` on a linux OS to see which file handles actually exist.

Comment: @ulferts https://gist.github.com/niuage/118879f9095dff3a3d76bbdbba8accc7 yes, apparently, `goals.png` (image_pipe in my post), is open a lot of times... So I guess it boils down to how to get RMagick to close these down...

Comment: You might be able to work around the issue (still no clue why it happens in the first place) by controlling the file operations yourself. I think [from_blob](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#from_blob) or [read_inline](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#read_inline) might help you once you have the image information pulled out by plain old [File](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html) operations.

Comment: I had the same thought :) and it works! You can post an answer with something like `while f = File.read(filename); image = Image.from_blob(f); [...]` and I'll accept it!

Comment: Ahh, I just joined you on finding out and it has been fun doing it. Go ahead and answer that question yourself. You can probably even describe it better than I can knowing more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find the root cause of the issue, but [ulferts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3206935/ulferts) helped me find a workaround that's acceptable for me.

Instead of letting RMagick open the file itself, we should handle it on our side, and then use `.from_blob` to create the `Magick::Image` instance.

```
while f = File.read(image_pipe)
  image = Image.from_blob(f)
  # ... do stuff with image.
end
```